# R/Shiny Plotly Proportional X-Axis Date Plotting

Tags: r, shiny, plotly

Could anyone please tell how I can plot proportional x-axis when plotting by dates-see attached?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the sequence of numbers `1,2,3,...` until `nrow(df)` as x variable, and supply your own tick marks. Example:

```
df = data.frame(date=c("1 Aug","1 Aug","2 Aug","3 Aug"),value=c(1,1.2,2,4))

plot_ly(df, x =1:nrow(df),
        y =~value,type="scatter",
        mode="lines") %>%
  layout(xaxis=list(tickmode = 'array',
                    tickvals = 1:nrow(df),
                    ticktext = df$date,
                    range = c(0.5, nrow(df)+0.5)))
```

Result:

[image]

Hope this helps!